# C++ - how to check type alignment requirements

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment

I want to copy different values of type `T`s to a `char` buffer and be able to use them later by using `reinterpret_cast`. Sample code:

```
template<typename T>
char* Append(char* buffer, const T& value)
{
    new(buffer) T(value);
    return buffer + sizeof(T);
}
```

Is it possible to check if `buffer` respects the alignment requirements of `T`? As an example where `buffer` doesn't respect alignment requirements of `T` is any chaining of `Append` calls with `sizeof(T0) < sizeof(T1)`

EDIT:

How can check if `new(buffer) T(value);` is valid knowing only the address and the type?

Comment: @MarcoA. I don't want to tweak the attributes. I just want to know if the `new(buffer)` is valid for type `T` from the `T'`s alignment requirement perspective.

Comment: See `std::aligned_storage`, `alignof` operator, `std::alignment_of`, `std::align()`

Comment: You just need to check that `buffer` is a multiple of `alignof(T)`.

Comment: @pmr: You can't really do that, since `buffer` is a pointer, and not an arithmetic type.

Comment: I made my mind a bit: you can't do that at compile-time since buffer is a pointer only known when that function is called. Unless you radically change the design and put some constraints there's no way that I see to achieve it

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't see why this should be a problem. You can always convert it to `inptr_t` and do arithmetic on it.

Comment: @pmr Yes to converting; no to doing arithmetic on it - at least, not in a portable manner. The only thing the standard guarantees about such a converted `intptr_t` is that you can convert it right back and get the same pointer; anything beyond that is implementation-defined. Memory architectures other than a flat address space do exist.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks, that clears up my confusion why this wouldn't be enough and why you really need `std::align`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
char* fixedBuffer = buffer;
fixedBuffer = std::align(alignof(T), sizeof(T), fixedBuffer, sizeOfBuffer);
if (!fixedBuffer) {
  // buffer is too small
} else if (fixedBuffer != buffer) {
  // buffer is misaligned; fixedBuffer points to the correctly aligned offset
} else {
  // buffer is aligned as-is.
}
```